# use JSP variable as id of an html element

Tags: html, jsp

I am generating a dynamic link in a JSP page, and I would like to use a JSP variable as the ID of the generated link.

Example:

```
<%int x=4;%> 
<a id ="<%x%>"  href ="#">
```

Basically, I want the link above to have the id 4 (content of the jsp variable x).

I tried the above code, but it did not work. I also tried to use c:out tag but it did not work. Any idea on how to do it?

Thanks .

Comment: what about <a id ="<%=x%>" href="#">   Expression tag

Comment: Still, it does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't really be using JAVA in your template files. You could set a variable using `<c:set />` and then output using `${var}` e.g.

```
<a id ="${var}"  href ="#">
```

Really you should be assigning variables to the correct scope in JAVA and then accessing that variable like `${obj.key}`

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSTL

```
<c:set value="4" var="x"></c:set>
```

JSP

```
<a id ="${x}"  href ="#" >${x}</a>
```

or Scriptlets

```
<%int x=4;%> 

<a id ="<%=x %>"  href ="#" ><%=x %></a>
```